# npm install -g npm does update, but doesnt show in npm -v

Tags: npm, ionic2

`npm install -g npm` (this installs npm@3.10.5)

`npm -v` (this shows old 2.7.4)

This problem is shown in below snapshot:

[image: this problem is shown in below snapshot]

Comment: Most probably your old npm is installed globally (in terms of Windows, not in terms of NPM) and is on PATH. The newly installed npm is not. You could try using the new npm from its path directly: `cd C:\Use...\node_modules` then `.\npm.exe`

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak thanks for your solution! 
But can I have a better one as i have to do this every time I want to use npm. can you suggest a simpler way, may be uninstall npm and node.js and install it back again ?

Comment: Just add the path of your newer NPM to your system path variable. It will take precedence over the older one. Look around the web for how this is done.

Comment: thanks mate this worked !